# Find substring and match until character appears

Tags: regex

I have want to extract the part that comes after url:' and up until i hit the next '

So basicly when doing the regexpt this is as far as I get url:[*.'] but that is wrong cause i dont want to include url in my match.

From the text below there should be 2 matches which gives me

```
/company/513092-1/jk-servicemontage-ab
/company/515413-1/energi-o-inneklimat-i-norrkoping-ab
```

My text file looks like.

```
[{company:'JK Servicemontage AB', kundnr:'513092-1', icon:'', url:'/company/513092-1/jk-servicemontage-ab', lat:'59.3159923', long:'18.277547599999934', adress:'Ripvägen 4 B 13247 SALTSJÖ BOO sweden'},{company:'Energi & Inneklimat i Norrköping AB', kundnr:'515413-1', icon:'', url:'/company/515413-1/energi-o-inneklimat-i-norrkoping-ab', lat:'58.59852349999999', long:'16.1451237', adress:'Fridhemsvägen 3 60213 NORRKÖPING sweden'}]
```

Comment: Instead of a regexp, why don't you use a real parser for the literal notation you're using (it looks like a Python list of dictionaries)? It would be best if you stored the data in a standard format like JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
(?<=url:').*?(?=')
```

- `(?<=url:')` - lookbehind for `url:'`
- `.*?`  - non-greedy findall
- `(?=')` - lookahead for closing quote `'`

[**Regex101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/nRhoPe/1)